# How to return the lowest value and name var from the list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a return list:

test<-list(`Test A`=5421.815, `Test B`=5032.269, `Test n`=6602.334 )

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | double 1 | List of lenght 7 |
| Test A | double 1 | 5421.815 |
| Test B | double 1 | 5032.269 |
| Test n | double 1 | 6602.334 |

The min(unlist(test)) or Reduce(min,test) commands only return the desired value but not the name of the corresponding test.

**5032.269**

Expected return:

**Test B 5032.269**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `which.min` to get the index of `min`imum value and then subset the `list` with that index

```
test[which.min(test)]
#$`Test B`
#[1] 5032.269
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test[Reduce(min, test) == test]
#$`Test B`
#[1] 5032.269
```

Or

```
test[min(unlist(test)) == test]

#$`Test B`
#[1] 5032.269
```